# get LHS and RHS of ICmpInst and FCmpInst in llvm?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

How can I get LHS and RHS of ICmpInst and FCmpInst in llvm?

I need these values of Sign, Code, Value *LHS, Value *RHS, Predicate. To do analysis of CmpInst. I could find all values except LHS, and RHS.
Any idea..

Comment: I couldn't find a method to access them.):

Comment: But some sort of code-attempt would be rather useful...

Answer (score 3):

I could figure it out.

```
CmpInst* CI= dyn_cast<CmpInst>(&*I);
Value * LHS = CI->getOperand(0);
Value * RHS = CI->getOperand(1);
```